# C# Code example to connect to elasticache using StackExchange.Redis for IAM authentication option

Tags: c#-3.0, stackexchange.redis, amazon-elasticache

For elasticache cluster configured to use Redis version 7 or above, there is an option to connect using IAM authentication. With IAM Authentication you can authenticate a connection to ElastiCache for Redis using AWS IAM identities.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/auth-iam.html

I am trying to get an example of working code with StackExchange.Redis client to authenticate requests to elasticache using IAM user

As per the documentation, I have tried the following :

- Create a role with given policies
- Created a user with IAM authentication mode
- Created signed token request and tried to pass it as a password while connecting with cluster

I am getting wrongpass:invalid-username-password error.

Comment: How did you pass the token? Did you also pass a username, or only password? 
Can you paste the code you tried already?